# Ubuntu 12.04 installation terminated due to fatal error

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I am trying to do this since along time now, I have windows 7 on my hdd but the boot loader seems to not work since I had already tried installing ubuntu once. how do I get the boot menu back? also, I am trying to make a new installation but it gives error just before the installation ends, the erroe reads as:

> executing-grub-install-dev/sda/3-failed-fatal-error

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` from your installing live media .How many internal hard disk do you have , also did you checked the iso image (md5sum)file before trying it out for installation.

Comment: Well which format did you selected for installation **ext2, ext3 or ext4**.

Comment: i selected ext2

Comment: Try using **ext4**, and please post your results.

Comment: no that did not

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you shouldn't have to do any manual partitioning as of newer Ubuntu distributions. Just leave a blank unformatted partition the size of your desired ubuntu installation and the setup will take care of the rest. Also remove the faulting previous Ubuntu partition to avoid this one being used instead of your fresh install.

If you want to use the MBR for Windows 7 instead, insert your Windows 7 installation media and select Repair > Command line. Then type BootRec.exe /fixmbr

If you suspect the iso being corrupt, this might be the best way to go about to be able to download a new iso and redo the Ubuntu installation media.

Answer (score 1):

You have to partition your HDD for Ubuntu properly.
You need 4 partition for Ubuntu

```
Type    PartitionFormat    Size

/boot   ext2                500MB <enough>
swap                        4000MB <If u want you can increase, but this is enough.>
/       ext4                <Its for application, give how much you want.>
/home   ext4                <Rest of space>
```

This will solve your problem of booting. it will reset boot loader. Thank you.

Comment: It is *not* necessary to have four separate partitions for an Ubuntu system. Ubuntu's installer, when asked to automatically partition, makes two. You *can* have those four partitions, if you want. But you don't have to, and **this is irrelevant to the problem in the question**. The boot loader will not fail to install as a consequence of the partition layout *being too simple*.